# Запрос на выборку из eav

Tags: sql, select, eav

Здрасьте!
Помогите составить запрос
вот к этим таблицам, (что то вроде eav)
[image: структура базы]
Либо если схема не правильная подскажите что не так

Задача1: выборка всех товаров и их атрибутов
В итоге я хочу получить многомерный массив где каждый товар будет такого вида:

```
[product_id] => 1
[product_name]=>tovar1
[color]=>array(

    [0] => white
    [1] => black
    [2] => green
)
[size]=>array(

    [0] => 42
)
```

Задача2: выборка конкретных товаров с конкретными атрибутами в таком же виде

в качестве БД использую PostgreSQL

у меня получается всё довольно криво:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, ak.attr_key_name, av.attr_value_name 
            FROM product as p
             INNER JOIN options as o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
             INNER JOIN attr_key as ak ON ak.attr_key_id = o.attr_key
             INNER JOIN attr_value as av ON av.attr_value_id = o.attr_value";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()){
    $data = $row;
}
```

Comment: запросе всегда возвращает таблицу, у которой только 2 измерения: колонки и строки. многомерную структуру он вернуть не может. Многомерную структуру вы должны создавать из этого на клиенте сами. т.е. в выборке добавить order by p.product_id а на клиенте, получая по одной строке (обычным fetch. fetchAll избыточен) следить за id продукта и когда он меняется добавлять новую строку в массив и далее заполнять ее

Comment: Да многомерный массив СУБД вернуть не может. Но проблема в том что в результирующей таблице очень много повторяющихся данных. Т.е на каждый атрибут товара выводится информация о всём товаре. И там ведь будут не только id и name а ещё 26 полей. Если вывод повторяющихся данных будет не сильно нагружать сервер, то на клиенте я без проблем сформирую нужный мне массив. Но на данный момент запрос который я использую не очень ефективен

Comment: А почему повторяющиеся данные это проблема ? если самому формировать массив

Comment: Допустим я вывожу по 40 товаров на страницу, у которых по 10 атрибутов товара. Получается что запрос вернёт 400 записей в которых около 30 колонок будут лишними. Как это отразится на скорости выполнения запроса?

Comment: Переклейка 4х таблиц и получение всего этого с разных областей диска займет минимум раз в 100 больше времени, чем передача этих лишних колонок. так что конкретно о колонках с точки зрения скорости волноваться вообще не стоит. А если смотреть на весь запрос в целом - то да, выборка из eav не самая быстрая штука. Но уходить от него совсем все равно нельзя, он позволяет искать за адекватное время. Если возникают проблемы с выборкой - то в БД носится избыточность и данные помимо eav хранятся например в одном поле в json (синхронизация триггерами). или добавляется кеш вне БД

Comment: Спасибо! Всё оказалось проще чем я думал...)